# Objective-Cでデリゲート用のプロトコルを実装する

Tags: xcode, objective-c

```
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapppushdelegate?language=objc
@protocol NEAppPushDelegate
- appPushManager:didReceiveIncomingCallWithUserInfo:
```

上記をObjective-Cのクラスに実装して使用したいと考えています。そこで、

Otameshi.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>
@interface Otameshi : NSObject <NEAppPushDelegate>
- (void)appPushManager:(NEAppPushManager *)manager didReceiveIncomingCallWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo API_AVAILABLE(ios(14.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos, tvos) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;
@end
```

Otameshi.m

```
#import "Otameshi.h"
@implementation Otameshi {（１）
    - (void)appPushManager:(NEAppPushManager *)manager didReceiveIncomingCallWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {（２）
    }
}
@end
```

のように実装したのですが、（１）で以下のようなワーニングが出ており、

```
Class 'Otameshi' does not conform to protocol 'NEAppPushDelegate'
Method definition for
'appPushManager:didReceiveIncomingCallWithUserInfo:' not found
```

（２）の「-」箇所で以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Expected ';' at end of declaration list Expected member name or ';'
after declaration specifiers Type name requires a specifier or
qualifier
```

[Objective-C プロトコルを理解する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/daisuke0131/items/9fd0c5392db07d441788)

を参考にプロトコルを拡張しようとしているのですが、足りていない箇所はありますでしょうか？

(Xcode12.4を使用しています）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最初に用語のことを言うと、(私がご質問内容を勘違いしているのでなければ)あなたが質問されているような事柄を「(プロトコルを)拡張する」と言う言い方はしません。「(プロトコルを)実装する」または「(プロトコルに)準拠させる」、「(プロトコルに)適合させる」と言うのが普通でしょう。

(Objective-Cでは、カテゴリーを使った「拡張」の形でプロトコルの実装を記述することがよくあるので、その辺の記事にある記述を混同されたのでしょうか？とりあえずご質問内のリンク中の記事には一切「拡張」と言う言葉は出てきませんが。)

#### 1点目 `@interface`に実装するプロトコロルのメソッド宣言は(普通は)書きません

完全に正確に書くのなら、書いても実害はありませんが、一文字でも間違えると意図せぬ結果となる可能性もありますので、普通は書きません。リンク先の記事でなぜわざわざ書いているのかは不明ですが、「普通は書かない」と思った方が良いでしょう。

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h>

@interface Otameshi : NSObject <NEAppPushDelegate>
@end
```

#### 2点目 `@implementation`に開始括弧(`{`)は不要

```
#import "Otameshi.h"

@implementation Otameshi // { <- ここには括弧は不要

- (void)appPushManager:(NEAppPushManager *)manager didReceiveIncomingCallWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //...
}

@end
```

Comment: OOPer様、丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。swiftでextentionされていたのをObjective-Cで書いてみようとしていたのですが、おっしゃる通り、カテゴリなどのサイトなどとごっちゃになり、紛らわしいタイトルとなってしまいました。「@interfaceに実装するプロトコロルのメソッド宣言は(普通は)書きません」勉強になりました。一度、Objective-Cの参考書を読み直してみます。

Comment: @kankomu さん、コメントありがとうございます。少なくともネット上の情報に関して言うと、Objective-Cは風前の灯状態で、やたらと古い記事や、中〜上級の経験がないと理解できないのではないか、と言った記事ばかりが検索結果の上位に来ることが多いようです。ただ書籍にはしっかりした内容のものもありますので、参考書をお持ちなら十分活用されると良いだろうと思います。しっかりしたもの＝やたらと分厚い、と言うことで、こちらのようなQ&Aサイトもバランスよく利用していかれることをお薦めします。

Comment: OOPer様、詳解 Objective-C 2.0 第3版という書籍を購入しました。まだ、動かしながら勉強していきたいと思います。